# Adding an action to the change record screen

Tags: django, django-admin

I read through the [tutorial on the Django site for adding custom admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) and got my custom action to work when viewing a list of items.

The problem is I'd like to add a button to the page where users can edit records that will execute this custom action, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Certainly. Apologies if I was being too vague. The tutorial on the Django site puts the custom function in the drop-down box of the 'select user to change' admin page. I'm trying to put a button that triggers that function on the page that edits an individual user.

Comment: Here's some screenshots that may make it a bit more clear. The tutorial to add custom functions puts the item in the dropdown box here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/_images/article_actions.png but I'd like it to go here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_images/admin05t.png

Comment: I guess you should be taking a different approach. Do not try to achieve this with 'custom admin actions'. See this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django-admin/index.html

Comment: The link is much appreciated. I think I can piece together what I need with that. :)